# How to save Python Json output as a CSV file using modules

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to get the data output I have, saved as an xlsm or csv file, but I don't grasp how I do that.
The code include one of my attempts

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter

BASE_URL = 'https://restapi.e-conomic.com/'
HEADERS = {
  'X-AgreementGrantToken': 'demo',
  'X-AppSecretToken': 'demo',
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
def get_invoice():
  url = "{0}/{1}".format(BASE_URL, 'invoices/booked')
  resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
  print(resp)
  print(resp.json())
  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo1.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
  worksheet.write(1, 1, resp)
  workbook.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  get_invoice()
```

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

*** EDIT ***

Hello again guys and girls,

I've gotten a little further than yesterday, by [following this answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350765/convert-json-to-csv-with-python-3)

```
import requests
import json
import csv

BASE_URL = 'https://restapi.e-conomic.com/'
HEADERS = {
  'X-AgreementGrantToken': 'demo',
  'X-AppSecretToken': 'demo',
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}


def get_invoice():
  url = "{0}/{1}".format(BASE_URL, 'invoices/booked')
  resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
  whale = (resp.json)
  print(resp)
  print(whale())
  output_fil = 'blab.csv'
  horse = len(whale) - 1

  data_til_fil = open(output_fil, 'w', newline='')
  csv_writer = csv.writer(data_til_fil, delimiter=";")
  csv_writer.writerow(["bookedInvoiceNumber","date","netAmount","vatAmount","grossAmount","dueDate"])

  for i in range(0, horse):
    meetup = whale[i]
    bookedInvoiceNumber = meetup['bookedInvoiceNumber']
    date = meetup['date']
    netAmount = meetup['netAmount']
    vatAmount = meetup['vatAmount']
    grossAmount = meetup['grossAmount']
    dueDate = meetup['dueDate']
    csv_writer.writerow([bookedInvoiceNumber,date,netAmount,vatAmount,grossAmount,dueDate])
    data_til_fil.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  get_invoice()
```

I have however still trouble with getting it to work, as it doesn't like my

```
horse = len(whale) - 1
```

line. Python responds with

```
TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

Is there anyone here who are patient enough to help me with this? I can say, a lot of people who uses e-conomic, would appreciate it, now and in the future. :-)

Comment: When you print `resp`, do you see what you expect? your *steps* look similar to [the xlsxwriter tutorial](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html)

Comment: Yes, I get all the data I want, or the 200 first responds of it, but it's apparently really hard to save that in an Excel file

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of the result of `print(resp)`?

Comment: Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/economicapi/rwd2ort4/ - just with https://restapi.e-conomic.com/invoices/booked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your new code.

1. resp.json is a method, so you need to call it to get the values (resp.json()). And the result is a map, I suppose you need to 'collection' to extract the content.

   In [17]: resp.json().keys()
   Out[17]: dict_keys(['collection', 'metaData', 'pagination', 'self'])
2. You closed the file too early, please move the close out of the for loop.

Please try below code and see whether that's what you wanted.

```
import requests
import json
import csv

BASE_URL = 'https://restapi.e-conomic.com/'
HEADERS = {
  'X-AgreementGrantToken': 'demo',
  'X-AppSecretToken': 'demo',
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}


def get_invoice():
    url = "{0}/{1}".format(BASE_URL, 'invoices/booked')
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    # whale = (resp.json)
    whales = resp.json()['collection']
    #print(resp)
    #print(whale())
    output_fil = 'blab.csv'
    horse = len(whales)

    data_til_fil = open(output_fil, 'w', newline='')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_til_fil, delimiter=";")
    csv_writer.writerow(["bookedInvoiceNumber","date","netAmount","vatAmount","grossAmount","dueDate"])

    #for i in range(0, horse):
    for meetup in whales:
        #meetup = whale[i]
        bookedInvoiceNumber = meetup['bookedInvoiceNumber']
        date = meetup['date']
        netAmount = meetup['netAmount']
        vatAmount = meetup['vatAmount']
        grossAmount = meetup['grossAmount']
        dueDate = meetup['dueDate']
        csv_writer.writerow([bookedInvoiceNumber,date,netAmount,vatAmount,grossAmount,dueDate])
    # you closed this file too early, pleaes make sure move this out of the for loop
    data_til_fil.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  get_invoice()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use worksheet.write, it only write to 1 specific cell, you wouldn't want to write every thing in a single cell, would you?
Ref to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35623260/7492424

Just replace

```
worksheet.write(1, 1, resp)
```

with

```
json_to_excel(worksheet, resp.json())

def json_to_excel(ws, data, row=0, col=0):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        row -= 1
        for value in data:
            row = json_to_excel(ws, value, row+1, col)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        max_row = row
        start_row = row
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            row = start_row
            ws.write(row, col, key)
            row = json_to_excel(ws, value, row+1, col)
            max_row = max(max_row, row)
            col += 1
        row = max_row
    else:
        ws.write(row, col, data)

    return row
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it returns       File 
    "C:/Users/User/Desktop/aaaab.py", line 21, in json_to_excel
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Sorry, you must be using Python3, please change to data.items()